# GLib-CRITICAL: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed - asked to log in twice

Tags: 14.04, kernel, login, syslog, gnome-session

Anything wrong with my gnome-session?

I turned my computer on, logged in, waited a little while (10-20 seconds) and then was asked to log-in again.  The second time it worked, but apport has asked me to report a problem.

Here is a bunch of errors from my syslog from that period of time:

```
May 16 09:44:03 lati kernel: [    1.383631] ata2.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued
May 16 09:44:03 lati kernel: [    1.383683] ata2.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
May 16 09:44:03 lati kernel: [    1.384126] ata2.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
May 16 09:44:03 lati kernel: [    1.699404] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init proximity plugin
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init time plugin
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init alert plugin
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
May 16 09:44:03 lati bluetoothd[480]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
May 16 09:44:04 lati kernel: [    2.332334] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
May 16 09:44:04 lati kernel: [    2.410635] systemd-udevd[392]: Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE: Invalid argument
May 16 09:44:05 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-12) Object not found
May 16 09:44:09 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
May 16 09:44:09 lati NetworkManager[793]: <error> [1494917049.163002] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:396] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
May 16 09:44:09 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
May 16 09:44:09 lati dnsmasq[2041]: warning: no upstream servers configured
May 16 09:44:09 lati kernel: [    7.317275] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
May 16 09:44:09 lati kernel: [    7.317280] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
May 16 09:44:09 lati kernel: [    7.317286] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
May 16 09:44:09 lati kernel: [    7.317756] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/etc/timidity/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/etc/timidity/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/etc/timidity/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/etc/timidity/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/etc/timidity/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/etc/timidity/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
May 16 09:44:10 lati pulseaudio[2231]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
May 16 09:44:11 lati kernel: [    9.678377] gnome-session[2444]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f0265f82794 sp 00007ffe2b3a56b0 error 4 in libICE.so.6.3.0[7f0265f78000+17000]
May 16 09:44:11 lati signond[2645]: ../../../../src/signond/signondaemon.cpp 388 init Failed to SUID root. Secure storage will not be available. 
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:17 lati NetworkManager[793]: <warn> error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.24': no such name
May 16 09:44:19 lati ModemManager[721]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3': Failed to find primary AT port
May 16 09:44:27 lati NetworkManager[793]: <info> (eth2): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
```

I guess the most interesting/relevant errors/warnings are those of the kernel.  In particular, look at the segmentation fault.
Can you see what's wrong with my machine?

---

System info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 4.4.0-75-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14

Comment: I get this constantly with undocking my Thinkpad W510 on Ubuntu 14.04. Your question shows up first in a search for "GLib-CRITICAL: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed". In my logs it is followed by `WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....`. So it isn't really a logout but more of a compiz killed issue as I can still do a `tmux attach` when I log back in to resume my terminal state.

Comment: Oh, just before the error in your question I do get `compiz[7646]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffc8b9ca598 error 14 in compiz[400000+3000]` which is probably the real culprit for compiz crashing.

Comment: Here is a bug report for the segfault error, no resolution though. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1380896

Comment: It appears a fix for this may have been released in a new version of Unity according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1366351